# How to get value in variable from Django template in views.py?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am working in django and want to pass the value in views.py 
my code is

template

```
     {% for doctor in doctor_list %}
       {% if citysearch == doctor.city %}
         <h1>Name of doctor is </h1>
          <form class="form" method="POST">
                  {% csrf_token %}
             <input type="submit", class="btn view", name="{{doctor.contactNumber}}" value="View Profile">
          </form>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

view

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selectdocnum = request.POST.get["doctor.contactNumber"]
        print(selectdocnum)
        return redirect('patientPannel')
```

This is not returning the value of doctor.contactNumber, and error is method object is not subscriptable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django is showing a method object is not subscriptable when submitting email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60632807/django-is-showing-a-method-object-is-not-subscriptable-when-submitting-email)

Answer (score 0):

`doctor.contactNumber` is a *value*, not a key that you should be using to lookup a value or as a name for a input field. give the input field a better name and use that instead. You're also using the wrong input type, either use `hidden` if you don't expect it to be edited, or something like `text` if it can be.

```
<input type="hidden" name="contactNumber" value="{{doctor.contactNumber}}">

request.POST.get("contactNumber")
```

Answer (score 0):

this is wrong,

```
<input type="submit", class="btn view", name="{{doctor.contactNumber}}" value="View Profile">
```

i think you have to do this

```
 {% for doctor in doctor_list %}
   {% if citysearch == doctor.city %}
     <h1>Name of doctor is </h1>
      <form class="form" method="POST">
              {% csrf_token %}
         <input type="text" value="{{doctor.contactNumber}}" name="doctorcontactnumber">
         <input type="submit" class="btn view" value="View Profile">
      </form>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

your views

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
    selectdocnum = request.POST.get["doctorcontactnumber"]
    print(selectdocnum)
    return redirect('patientPannel')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's normal, `request.POST.get` is a method. Use parenthesis.The right call is:

```
selectdocnum = request.POST.get("doctorcontactnumber")
```

For your input, you have jumbled `name` and `value`. Do this instead:

```
<input type="hidden" name="doctorcontactnumber" value="{{doctor.contactNumber}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit", class="btn view", name="number" value="{{doctor.contactNumber}}">
if request.method == 'POST':
    selectdocnum = request.POST.get("number")
    print(selectdocnum)
    return redirect('patientPannel')
```

in place of value you have to use the {{doctor.contactNumber}} and you have to get the data using the name(request.POST.get("number")) then it will get the data